# Meaning of 'get off something'

Tags: phrase-meaning

As I look up the dictionary, it says that 'to get off' means 1. to start off / to leave for somewhere 2. to stop something 3. to escape

But I don't understand the meaning of 'to get off opinions'. Does that mean like, making opinions? Here is the example, which is from 'Baker's blue-jay yarn' by Mark Twain.

*He couldn't seem to make it out, so he raised a yell, and three more jays come. They all examined the hole, they all made the sufferer tell it over again, then they all discussed it, and **got off** as many leather-headed opinions about it as an average crowd of humans could have done.*

Answer (score 3):

*Get off* here is a transitive colloquialism, a 'phrasal' verb meaning approximately "succeed in emitting".

> He got off several shots at the bandits, but they escaped unhurt.
>   He got off some telling observations before the crowd pelted him off the stage.